# Pandas get dummies() for numeric categorical data

Tags: pandas, encoding, categorical-data

I have 2 columns:

- Sex (with categorical values of type string as 'male' and 'female')
- Class (with categorical values of type integer as 1 to 10)

When I execute `pd.get_dummies()` on the above 2 columns, only 'Sex' is getting encoded into 2 columns. But 'Class' is not converted by get_dummies function.

I want 'Class' to be converted into 10 dummy columns as well, similar to One Hot Encoding.

Is this expected behavior? Is there an workaround?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can convert values to strings:

```
df1 = pd.get_dummies(df.astype(str))
```

Comment: Great! Thank you for your help :-)

Comment: The problem with this answer is that you'll run into issues with "classes" that aren't in the dataset. For example: Let's say you never see Class == '7' in the dataset. The get_dummies function will only return 9 columns instead of 10. After training an algorithm (I'm assuming that's what you're doing) and you feed it a Class = 7 feature there is no way to handle it.

Comment: @RedM - I think it is more complicated, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18280652)

Comment: Yup, that's exactly the problem you'll run into.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't want to convert your data, you can use 'columns' argument in *get_dummies*. Here is quick walkthrough:

Here is the data frame reproduced per your description:

```
sex_labels = ['male', 'female']
sex_col = [sex_labels[i%2] for i in range(10)]
class_col = [i for i in range(10)]
df = pd.DataFrame({'sex':sex_cols, 'class':class_col})
df.sex = pd.Categorical(df.sex)
```

The dtypes are:

```
print(df.dtypes)
sex      category
class       int64
dtype: object
```

Apply get_dummies:

```
df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['sex', 'class'])
```

Verify:

`print(df.columns)`

Output:

```
Index(['sex_female', 'sex_male', 'class_0',
'class_1','class_2','class_3','class_4','class_5',
'class_6','class_7','class_8','class_9'],dtype='object')
```

Per the docs at, https://pandas.pydata.org/pandasdocs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html,

> If columns is None then all the columns with object or category dtype
>   will be converted

This is the reason you only see dummies for sex column and not for class.

Hope this helps. Happy learning!

*Note: Tested with pandas version '0.25.2'*

Comment: Note that there is already an accepted answer to this question.